# Temporarily change an Excel's cell displaying value while updating values

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to design a form to proportionally subtract a number (which already entered in an Userform TextBox) from two specific cells and temporarily see the outcome without actually/permanently changing those cell values. (For example subtracting number 54 proportionally from two cells which currently have 353 and 158 as their values)

Comment: You can't change the value in a cell without actually changing the value (or formula) of a cell, but you could use a [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables) to store the value temporarily, and then "put it back" when it want it restored to the original value. There are several ways to [refer to worksheet cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/reference-cells-and-ranges) from VBA.

Comment: ...or I suppose, if you wanted to get sneaky about it, you can have a [user form](https://support.microsoft.com/office/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-15ba7e28-8d7f-42ab-9470-ffb9ab94e7c2) open, [sized](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.width) and [positioned](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.top) exactly the same as the cell, so it only "seems" like you're changing the value. I guess another sneaky way would be to display the alternate value with custom cell formatting. Your [mcve] would help us help you. (See [ask])

Comment: @braX I was at the design step, I wanted to make sure there isn't a built-in Excel feature for this purpose, Thanks

Comment: @ashleedawg How about using Excel's "What if Analysis" tool?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly *"elegant"*, but I suppose you could use a [custom number format](https://support.microsoft.com/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68) to have the cell show a different value than whatever it actually contains.

```
Sub run_demo() 'temporarily formats A1 to show custom message
  showValue ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), "Please wait!"
End Sub

Sub showValue(myCell As Range, tmpValue As String)
  Dim origFormat As String

  origFormat = myCell.NumberFormat 'store original cell format
  myCell.NumberFormat = """" & tmpValue & """"  'display custom message

  '...now do whatever u gotta do:
  Application.CalculateFull 'for example you could force recalculation
  pause 3  '(pausing 3 seconds, just for demo)
  
  myCell.NumberFormat = origFormat 'replace original cell format
End Sub

Sub pause(sec As Single)
  Dim t As Single: t = Timer 'get current time
  Do: DoEvents: Loop While Timer < t + 3 'wait til [sec] secs elapsed
End Sub
```

...but I guess if you're going to bother with that, you could also **just store the *actual* cell value** (unless it is relevant to sheet recalculation, in which case this method would work since the cell's formatting won't affect the calculation -- in theory, anyway.)

<sup>I'm not clear on your goal (your question is a little [vague](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and lacking in any [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried) but regardless, I can't help but feel that there's probably a better way to do it. (I sometimes find it helpful to *"[take a step back](https://tinybuddha.com/blog/taking-step-backward-can-way-forward/)"*, re-analyze your goal, and tackle it from a different angle.)</sup>

[image: Take a step back]